# angularjs extends directive Configuration - directive is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm reading the amazing wiki tutorial
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#specialized-the-directive-configuration

and I've tried like

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainController',function() {

});
app.directive('one', function() {
    return {
            template: '<div>I am one</div>',
            controller:function(){

            },
            link:function($scope){

            }
        };
    });
app.directive('two', function() {
        return angular.extend({}, oneDirective[0], { template: '<div>I am two</div>' });     
});
```

but I've got ReferenceError: oneDirective is not defined

so what's the matter, please ?

Comment: oneDirective is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to inject the first directive into the second one:

```
app.directive('two', function(oneDirective) {
    return angular.extend({}, oneDirective[0], { template: '<div>I am two</div>' });     
});
```